# Create thread safe global store in C

Tags: c, store, freertos

I'm writing an application running on FreeRTOS where I have different threads that all have to access (read and some write) the same data structures.
So I thought I could implement a global data store holding all the data in some grouped structs. I also thought about using something like SQLite but I think that's an overkill for my application.

Nevertheless there are some open questions

1. To guarantee thread safety I assume I need to add a semaphore for my read and write access but...
2. If a thread only has to update certain elements of a struct I'd need to hand it a pointer to that struct, but as soon as I start using pointer references I can no longer protect my access with a semaphore. So how can I allow a thread to modify single struct elements without violating thread safety?
3. Is there a better way to have something like a `global store` than the one I planned to use? Google didn't give much hints.

Comment: What is the problem with semaphore? It is supported in FreeRTOS. What is the number of structures?

Comment: I grouped it into 6 structures (some are bigger some are smaller). The problem I have with the semaphores (maybe I got something wrong) is, how would I modify data via pointer reference protected with a semaphore? Add a function to `lock()` and `unlock()` the semaphore from a thread before it modifies the struct? Cause If I'd modify the data by value I'd add a function to the store like `void version_info_to_store(version_info data)` and then lock the semaphore within this function.

Comment: The protection with semaphore is matter of organization. You will not directly protect the structure from access but use the semaphore as flag "structure is currently in use". The flag is not simple variable but semaphore to be sure that task switch will not hit between `if` and `flag = 1` in: `if ( flag == 0 ) { flag = 1; modify_structure; flag = 0; }`. You have to guarantee that every access to structure is protected by the same semaphore - this is the "organization". (Note: this is only a solution, maybe not the best.)

Comment: So the modifying task is requesting access to the struct before modifying the store? That's what I meant with `lock()` and `unlock()` function implemented in the store itself.

Comment: Yes, I think it is similar. Not sure whether one global semaphore (lock/unlock) for all structures will work well or is better to have separate protection for each structure.

Comment: Yes I'm not sure about that either, in addition I'd probably have a lot of concurrent read access but rather small amount of write access, so maybe I don't want to block the read access against each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me share with you the most common C-way to handle this type of scenarios.

In order to avoid exposing a lot of global data, use `opaque pointer`s and have a list of APIs that take the opaque pointer as a parameter. In this way you can have a clean set of APIs to access all of your structures leaving the implementation specifics just in the *.c* file. The good thing about using *opaque pointer*s is that no one knows how to deal with the type pointed-to-data except for the APIs that takes in opaque pointer as a parameter. This provides protection & encapsulation to your structures, so that they are ever accessed or mutated with the APIs that you provide.

In each of the structure definitions identified by the opaque pointers, have a `mutex` (*FreeRTOS has mutex implemented in-terms of semaphores*) to access the structure members in a thread-safe manner. You have to use `xSemaphoreCreateMutex` when creating the mutex. In all your APIs use `xSemaphoreGive` & `xSemaphoreTake` when you want to access the member data that are potentially accessed by multiple tasks.

Comment: If I understood you correctly that would mean if I have a struct holding 10 different values which I want to be able to individually modify, I'd then need to add an API with a getter and setter for each of these 10 values?

Comment: @Humpawumpa Well, it depends. If you want to access them individually  you need 10 apis. Otherwise you can have 1 api to retrieve or access the entire `record` in an atomic manner. I assume that you would make `record` a sub-structure inside your main structure  identified by the `opaque pointer`.